# Split to four equal size subnets

Tags: ip, subnet

Question;
Suppose an ISP owns the block of addresses of the form `128.119.40.64/25.` Suppose it wants to create four subnets from this block, with each block having the same number of IP addresses. What are the prefixes (of form a.b.c.d/x) for the four subnets?

Answer;

```
Four equal size subnets: 128.119.40.64/28, 128.119.40.80/28, 128.119.40.96/28,
128.119.40.112/28.
```

It is interesting because netmask is 25. and if we split out to 4 subnet we should take 2 bit from host.
and will be `25+2= 27.`

why netmask is not 27? why 28?

Comment: [This two-part answer](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53994/8499) to the question linked above explains subnetting, including same size and variable size subnet, in detail.

Comment: @RonMaupin in there, they explain that as like i said.  netmask 27.
but above, in the answer, netmask is 28.

Comment: Did you read the note that explains why your class does it that way, even though it is wrong? Then, look at the first subnet in your answer. In any case, all "_education, certification, or homework_" questions are explicitly off-topic here. We will tell you how to arrive at the answer, but we will not give you the answer, especially when it is a wrong answer required for a class.

Comment: I dont want to answer. i like to understand the question. when i wrote this message, i found it. thank you but. i will say again. i didnt want to answer.
just i didnt understand when i first read. (cus my bad english.)

actually you send me this page yesterday. and i read several times. i learnt much. but i need to read much more times. sorry btw for this topic. another time i create a topic according to rule.